# Does Tivoli Storage Manager for backup get the details right?

Tags: backup

I know that Carbon Copy Cloner, Time Machine, and other Mac-specific software goes to significant lengths to back up Macs correctly, with all the fiddly details right: permissions, file attributes, etc. My company uses Tivoli Storage Manager as the standard backup solution, and there's a Mac version.

**Does Tivoli get the details right too?** I.e., if I restore, I don't want to hassle with reinstalling apps or discover over a period of months that there's subtle breakage.

I'm on Lion if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that Tivoli gets these finer details absolutley correct.

In terms of backing up files and applications these are fine, but when it comes to passwords, attributes and preferences etc, then no, not always.

I have just spoken to a pal who uses IBM systems in a Mac and PC magazine publishing environment and prefers his staff on Macs to use Time Machine as the standard back-up to their servers, rather than the PC users who use Tivol as standard.

Comment: Ouch for Tivoli and for the asker then :)

Comment: @Gio there are plenty of free options for mac that work very well so it is better to use these anyway, such as Time Machine

Comment: I know, I don't use it myself. But if even Time Machine is better than Tivoli, good luck with that :)

Comment: Tivoli is very very good with PC's and with some Linux based things, but when it comes to mac, IBM is far from caring.